# The call stack never gives the location of the error

Tags: c#, runtime-error, callstack

I use Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone. When an error occurs during run time, I look in the Call stack window, but there are onlu systems functions there, and the last one, where the program stopped :

File : App.xaml.cs

Function : Application_UnhandledException

The function where the error really happened can never be found there. Is there an option to check to make this window display (if possible, only) usefull information ? Or is there another windows that should be used instead ?

Comment: This might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402572%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Exceptions dialog, set the debugger to [Break on User-Unhandled Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/038tzxdw.aspx).

In Visual Studio's menu, Open Debug -> select Exceptions... ->  check the first Checkbox for the **Command Language Runtime Exceptions**.

Edit: just notice that you are using Express version of 2012. As per the link,

> To enable the Exceptions menu in Express versions, on the Tools menu, click Settings, and then select Expert Settings.